# XSD: How to make the integer range of a value dependent on other element?

Tags: xml, xsd, integer, attributes, assert

This is the second time I ask this question:
In an XML document (using Version 1.1) an element `random` has two integers: An integer `start` that normally only should have a range of value from `min=1` and `max=9`. And an integer `end` that is always supposed to be bigger then start with a max value of `max=10`. Being defined like this:

```
    <xs:complexType name="random">
        <xs:attribute name="start">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                    <xs:minInclusive value="1"/>
                    <xs:maxInclusive value="9"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:attribute>
        <xs:attribute name="end">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                    <xs:minInclusive value="2"/>
                    <xs:maxInclusive value="10"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:attribute>
        <xs:assert test="@start le @end"/>
    </xs:complexType>
```

But now in some rare cases when there is the attribute `bigValue` in another element present, I want these integers to actually be able to have a much higher value. To achieve that I can have the element `random` as a child-element of the complexType-item `annotation` which is defined in the XSD-file like this:

```
    <xs:complexType name="annotation" mixed="true">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="random" type="random" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="annotation">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:union memberTypes="comments dice"/>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:attribute>
 <---- INSERT ASSERT HERE ---->
    </xs:complexType>
```

For example in a case where `bigValue` is defined, `start` is supposed to have a value of 20 and `end` of 50:

```
<annotation extended='bigValue'/><random start='20' end='50'/>
```

Is there any way how to do that without having to change the value range of `start` and `end` (because in almost all other cases it is not supposed to be bigger than 9 or respectively 10). Can this be achieved with an assert for example? Or is this not possible at all and the better approach is to limit the max values by an assert if `bigValue` is absent?
I already tried plenty of assertions like the following ones but all of them fail to compile, only throwing the "XPST0003 - Assertion XPath expression couldn't compile successfully"-error. Here is what I tried:

```
<xs:assert test="if exists(annotation/bigValue) or every $x in .//@random.start satisfies $x le 10"/>
<xs:assert test="exists(annotation/bigValue) or every $x in .//@random.start satisfies $x le 10"/>
<xs:assert test="if ((random) and (annotation) and exists(annotation/bigValue)) or every $x in .//@random.start satisfies $x le 10"/>
```

Additionally I tried a restructured assert for the case that the value of start and end are defined higher to begin with. But even though I found an assert that compiled, it broke the XML-document completely telling me on any element that the assertion evaluation didn not succeed so I had to delete it as well. The assert I used was:

```
<xs:assert test="if (random.start le 9) then (annotation.annotation = 'bigValue') else not(random.start le 9)"/>
```

So at this point I'm fairly clueless and confused how to do it. Can you please help me?

Comment: While asking an XSD question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSD that tried to implement it.
(3) XSD processor and its conformance with the XSD standards: 1.0, or 1.1.

Comment: You completely lost me on your comment. I have provided all of that haven't I?
The first 2 examples are my XSD-code, the third one is the XML-code in question and the last 2 examples are the asserts that I have unsuccessfully tried.

Comment: (1) Before XML could be valid, it shall be well-formed. (2) XML Schema is nowhere to be seen: `<xsd:schema...</xsd:schema>`, just bits and pieces. (3) is missing. Overall, a minimal reproducible example means that we can run your use case as-is by using your XML/XSD pair sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first and third `xs:assert` attempts are clearly nonsense: an XPath `if` expression needs parentheses around the condition and `then` and `else` clauses. The fact that you attempt this and have no idea why it's wrong casts serious doubt on how you are approaching the task - you seem to be trying to write code by trial and error, without using any reference material to guide you.

The second attempt is closer, but if you enter this as an XPath expression into the XPath box in Oxygen, it tells you what is wrong:

```
exists(annotation/bigValue) or every $x in .//@random.start satisfies $x le 10
```

**Unexpected token 'every' at start of expression**

It needs to be

```
exists(annotation/bigValue) or (every $x in .//@random.start satisfies $x le 10)
```

which is syntactically valid. However, I suspect you don't have an attribute called `@random.start`, instead I suspect you were trying to refer to the `@start` attribute of the `random` element, which would be `.//random/@start`.

Comment: This was still not working as intended but when I changed the assert, it finally worked: `<xs:assert test="(@annotation = 'bigValue') or ((every $x in .//random/@start satisfies $x le 9) and (every $x in .//random/@end satisfies $x le 10))"/>`
Your hint finally brought me much closer to the solution.
But with these asserts I always feel like stumbling around in the nebula. They are neither intuitive nor can you find any good source on how to teach yourself with them. Always pure trial and error >.<